# How do I create a form with input value as date, and creates permalink of the date eg. example.com/dd-mm-yy upon submission

Tags: html, forms

Here is the form I created:

```html
<div align="center">
  <form id="example_form" action="/">
    <fieldset>
      <legend></legend><input id="date" type="date" value="today" />

      <input class="formbutton" type="submit" value="submit" /></fieldset>
  </form>
  <form action="#" method="post"></form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following: This is very basic code where form action will be URL of the page.

```
<form action="/action_page.php" method="get" target="_blank">
    Date: <input type="date" type="date" value="today"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="formbutton">
</form>
```